# Is having a active MySQL Connection for long periods of time bad?

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm developing an MMORPG, it's pretty far along.

However, I'm noticing now that the MySQL Server has a automatic connection terminate time limit. So after x time, a connection is terminated. So what's happening with my server is after about 8 hours of run time, users can't login or update their characters on logout.

A simple fix would be to make the time out value very very large, but I want to know if this is a bad idea?

Another solution would be, to check if the connection is still valid before making a SQL Query, and if not start a new connection. Although I prefer the first option if it has no bad side-effects.

Comment: The users will be connecting to your SQL server directly? Why not have them connect to a service and that service connect to the db. That way you can avoid the timeout from MySQL and you can validate the information being passed. If users have direct access to DB, they can potentially do bad things.

Comment: No users dont connect to the db directly. A user connects to my Server, and then from the server preforms queries on the sql server depending on what the user does. Although a user only ever interacts with the sql on two occasions anyways (when they log in to load all the account information into memory, and on logout to save all the account information to database).

Comment: If they are connecting to your server, the server should close the connection after the request is made, and then open a new request each time they need to do something with the DB. This will avoid the timeouts.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to just keep one global connection that is always open then to be starting a new connection everytime a user logs in or logs off?

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors, so unfortunately, I can't answer that with 100% certainty for your specific situation. If it matters, I've never seen a performance hit by doing it the way I described.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're not already doing that I'd like to say that the best option would be to use a proper [connection pool](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1ConnectionPool.html) on the server instead of reusing a single connection.

Now, increasing the timeout SHOULD be safe, but MySQL *might* have memory leaks (of sorts) that are tied to the connection, so dropping the connection from time to time might be much safer.

For example, if you're using dynamically generated prepared queries (some APIs do that to make the queries safe from the SQL injection attacks) then MySQL might have a problem caching all the prepared queries in memory.

You might have to implement such eviction yourself, unfortunately.